# Create SSO class in visualforce that generates a SAML 2.0 protocol message

Tags: visualforce, single-sign-on, xml

Been looking for examples to for a SSO redirect class that generates a SAML 2.0 protocol message and redirects to AzureAD login.

Doesn't seem to be anything out there regarding this so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use out of the box setup? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-saas-salesforce-tutorial

Comment: @identigral I need to implement this on the force.domain not my.domain, send/receive assertion/assertion response within the class.

Comment: What SF product/edition/license is your force.com site using?